# cpp: expected primary-expression before ‘.’ token

Tags: c++, class, static, static-members

I have the following code:

```
class SSLHashSHA1
{
    SSLHashSHA1();
    ~SSLHashSHA1();
    public:
        static OSStatus update(string*, int*);
        static OSStatus final (string*, string*);
};

OSStatus SSLHashSHA1::update(string* ctx, int* ran){
    return 0;
}

OSStatus SSLHashSHA1::final(string* ctx, string* out){
    return 0;
}

static OSStatus SSLVerifySignedServerKeyExchange(
    SSLContext *ctx, bool isRsa, SSLBuffer signedParams, uint8_t *signature, uint16_t signatureLen)
{
    OSStatus err;

    if ((err = SSLHashSHA1.update(&hashCtx, &serverRandom)) != 0)
        goto fail;
    if ((err = SSLHashSHA1.update(&hashCtx, &signedParams)) != 0)
        goto fail;
        goto fail;
    if ((err = SSLHashSHA1.final(&hashCtx, &hashOut)) != 0)
        goto fail;


    fail:
        SSLFreeBuffer(&signedHashes);
        SSLFreeBuffer(&hashCtx);
        return err;
}
```

And i get the error mentioned in the heading.
I get that for the SSLHashSHA1.update and SSLHashSHA1.final calls.
Why do I get that?

I thought when I make class member functions static I can use the without having to create an object. Or should i change the class into a struct or something like that?

Comment: Write `SSLHashSHA1::update(&hashCtx, &serverRandom)` to call static member functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SSLHashSHA1.update()
```

This is totally wrong, `SSLHashSHA1` is a class, not an instance, so you can't use the `.` operator to invoke a method here, instead, as you mentioned, that your `update` is a static function, hence call it using the scope-resolution operator (`::`) like this :

```
SSLHashSHA1::update(&hashCtx, &serverRandom))
```